# Turning a piecewise affine optimization problem into an equivalent linear program

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, linear-programming, linearization

> $$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^4}{\text{minimize}} & x_1 + 6 x_2 - \min\{10x_3, 5x_4\} + \left| \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i \right| \\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i \ge \left| \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{3} i x_i \right| \\ & x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \ge 0 \end{array}$$

---

**My solution:**

First let $z=|\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i|$, and let $t=\min\{10x_3,5x_4\}$. Now we get the following problem: 
$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^4,z}x_1+6x_2-t+z$. 
S.t. 
$\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i\ge |\sum_{i=1}^{3}i*x_i|$. 
$z=|\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i|$. 
$t\le 10x_3$, $t\le 5x_4$.
$x_i\ge 0, \forall i=1,2,3,4$. 

Now, We notice that for every optimal solution $z$, there must be equality in the constraint $z=|\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i|$, (we can assume that there exists an optimal solution $z$ such that $z>|\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i|$, but that means that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $z-\epsilon$ lowers our function value, and we get contradiction that $z$ is an optimal solution). So we can write: $z\ge|\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i|$ and still keep the same problem.
And we have:
$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^4,z}x_1+6x_2-t+z$. 
S.t. 
$\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i\ge \sum_{i=1}^{3}i*x_i$. 
$\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i\le -\sum_{i=1}^{3}i*x_i$. 
$z\ge \sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i$. 
$z\le -\sum_{i=1}^{4}x_i$.
$t\le 10x_3$, $t\le 5x_4$.
$x_i\ge 0, \forall i=1,2,3,4$.
And that's my final answer.
Little question: Do I need to add $z$ to $\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^4,z}$? why? 
Any feedback is really appreciated, thanks in advance!
**EDIT:**
I've noticed that I have no logic behind changing $t = \min\{10x_3,5x_4\}$ with $t\le 10x_3$ and $t\le 5x_4$, Since this is a minimum problem, I'm not sure that the optimal solutions are the same! Any help?

Comment: Looks correct. The reason you can use $t$ is that you know $t$ is guaranteed to be smaller or equal to both $10x_3$ and $5x_4$, i.e. smaller or equal to the minimum. As $t$ is maximized in the objective, it will always be optimal to make it as large as possible, meaning it will activate one of those two constraints, thus making it equal to the minimum. Your minimization is over $(x,z,t)$.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thank you! I just noticed again that we are subtracting $t$, now it makes sense

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly?  It is unbounded, as you can see by taking $x=(0,0,c,2c)$ for arbitrarily large $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors (essentially the same error twice): in the second constraint for linearizing each absolute value, the $\le$ should instead be $\ge$.

Also, if the problem really imposes that each $x_i \ge 0$, you can simply remove the absolute values.  For example, replace $|\sum_i x_i|$ with just $\sum_i x_i$ because these two expressions are equal.

Comment: Thanks alot for pointing out that I didn't even need to deal with any absolute value here, but I don't get what's the mistake? if I reached that $z\ge |q|$, then that implies $z\ge q$ and $z \le -q$, I just used it to get rid of absolute value thought, I can now remove it all, but I still don't exactly get why it is a mistake. Thanks again

Comment: $z \ge |q| = \max(q,-q)$ is equivalent to $(z \ge q) \land (z \ge -q)$.

Comment: Oh what a mistake! Thanks for pointing that out! I don't know why I went for it as $|z|\ge q$. Now it's all clear!